# Checkbox in ListView (MVVM) | Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I'm creating ToDo app in Xamarin forms. I have a problem with Checkbox in Listview where are displayed ToDos. I can't find out how to get ToDo after checkbox is checked...

Checkbox in XAML:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
```

Method for getting information if checkbox is checked in ViewModel:

```
    private bool isChecked;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return isChecked; }
        set
        {
            if (isChecked != value)
            {
                isChecked = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsSelected"));
                    App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Title", " item have been selected", "Cancel");

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'd be grateful for every suggestion how to implement into MVVM.

Comment: Hi Martin I think that you should put this line in the listview IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=NameofYourcheckbox, Path=IsChecked}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVVM approch:

If your checkbox is inside List then its `binding property` will be in your `Model` and **not** in the `ViewModel`.
To get all the checked value you can use `LinQ`, `Where`clause to get data from your list based on condition where bool `IsChecked` is `true`

Example of `Where` clause can be:

```cs
var CheckedItemList= yourList.Where(m => m.IsChecked== true).ToList();
```

Please refer below link to know more about  [how list bindings work in MVVM](https://almirvuk.blogspot.com/2017/02/xamarinforms-listview-simple-mvvm.html)

Comment: Thank you very much, it works fine. I didn't realize that is a property of ToDo, so that's why I put **IsChecked** into ViewModel.

Comment: Please could you tell where to put this line of code: `var CheckedItemList= yourList.Where(m => m.IsChecked== true).ToList();`

Comment: Okay, so when do you want to get that, like you can have some button there and on clicking that you can get all selected items, or anywhere else?

Comment: I want to make it, that when the checkbox is checked the todo will be removed from the list. Is it possible to make it like that?

Comment: I guess you need to share the screenshot of that, for better understanding edit your question, or ask a new question.